# R: Multiple variables in GLM (one polynomial one sinusoidal)

Tags: r, variables, glm

I have some data where power, wind speed and wind direction have been measured. There's a second degree polynomial correlation between power and wind speed, and there's maybe a sinusoidal correlation between power and wind direction. I need to investigate that and get the Beta-values and p-values and see how well the model fits.

So I have two variables, which might influence power. The model needs to be a Generalized Linear Model.

I'm a newbie to R, but I've tried different approaches but couldn't find one. I have one matrix where all the data is collected. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for your `Generalized Linear Model`(glm) would be for example `power ~ wind speed + wind direction`.

You could perform this glm with the following code:

```
lmfit <- glm(power ~ wind_speed + wind_direction, dataset)
```

To analyse the model you may do `summary(lmfit)`. For more information on analysing the data you can check out [this page](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/multregr.html)

For more information about glm check out [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) link for more information about the `glm` function. Or search for some tutorials on how to perform linear models in R, like [this one](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAFahUKEwiLn8qN0IjJAhXKXhoKHWwvAYg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.tamu.edu%2F~alawing%2Fmaterials%2FESSM689%2FGLMtutorial.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGnjhr_uWqAsDTFj_1RvIYjnbr2ow&sig2=aQ0gZRNeFvciX4WUs4JSAg)

**Edit:** followup question:

Personally I do the following:

```
formula <- power ~ wind_speed + wind_direction + windspeed2 + sinwd
lmfit <- glm(formula, dataset)
```

It should also work if you do the following:

```
windspeed2 <- windspeed^2
sinwd <- sin(wind_direction)
formula <- power ~ wind_speed + wind_direction + windspeed2 + sinwd
lmfit <- glm(formula, dataset)
```

Comment: So how do I set wind speed to have a polynomial corelation and the wind_direction to have a sinusidal corelation?

Comment: Can I just create a variable called windspeed2 <- windspeed^2 and then add it to the model. And then create a model called sinwd<-sin(wind_direction) ? Will that help if I do the glm(power ~ wind_speed + wind_speed2 + sinwd, data=powerwind)

Comment: @Danny yes, that should work. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much... I can't even give you an arrow up, because I don't have 15 reputation :)

Comment: You can accept my answer as correct:) you can always upvote later if you want

Comment: I will :) Now If I want to make a log transformation of the power, can I just take lm(power) and then do the same thing over? I'm sorry... this is the last question :) I have normalized the power-values so that they are from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Danny I'm actually not sure! You could just try it out and look at the summary to see if you get results you are expecting! I'm unable to test this for you now :)

Comment: @Danny Did you try if it worked? I cannot test it as I don't have your data. Also simply using lm(power) will yield an invalid formula. What do you mean exactly by getting the log transformation of the power, getting the log transformation before calculating the model, or afterwards on the residuals?